# Unable to load assets image

Tags: image, flutter

I'm want to make a simple flutter app and want to add an image from my assets, I already try but the image still unable to load.
This is how I load the image

`Image.asset('assets/images/food.jpg')`

pubspec.yaml code :

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
  - assets/images/food.jpg
```

debug:

```
I/flutter (18975): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (18975): Unable to load asset: assets/images/food.jpg
I/flutter (18975): Unable to load asset: assets/images/food.jpg
I/flutter (18975):
I/flutter (18975): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (18975): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter (18975): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (18975): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:433:44)
I/flutter (18975): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (18975): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:418:14)
I/flutter (18975): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:285:105)
I/flutter (18975): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:157:22)
I/flutter (18975): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:285:82)
I/flutter (18975): (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (18975):
I/flutter (18975): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/food.jpg")
I/flutter (18975): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#df91c(), name: "assets/images/food.jpg",
I/flutter (18975): scale: 1.0)
```

This is my image folder look like :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your formatting is not as require in pubspec.yaml. you have to add one tab as it can be seen from your code.

Like this:

```
flutter:
   assets:
   - graphics/background.png
```

for more details look at this.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images